# Does not contain a definition for GetDataFromNumber But i have it defined?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string text = textBox1.Text;
    Mainform = this;

    this.Hide();

    GetSchedule myScheduleFinder = new GetSchedule();
    string result = myScheduleFinder.GetDataFromNumber(text);// says there is no definition
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter A Valid ID Number!");
    }
}
```

says it does not contain definition for it but on my GetSchedule .cs file i have it defined

```
public string GetDataFromNumber(string ID)//defined here
{

    foreach (IDnumber IDCandidateMatch in IDnumbers)
    {

        if (IDCandidateMatch.ID == ID)
        {
            StringBuilder myData = new StringBuilder();
            myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.Name);
            myData.AppendLine(": ");
            myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.ID);
            myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.year);
            myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.class1);
            myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.class2);
            myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.class3);
            myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.class4);
            //return myData;
            return myData.ToString();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

GetSchedule Class

public class GetSchedule
    {
        public GetSchedule()
        {
            IDnumber[] IDnumbers = new IDnumber[3];
            IDnumbers[0] = new IDnumber() { Name = "Joshua Banks", ID = "900456317", year = "Senior", class1 = "TEET 4090", class2 = "TEET 3020", class3 = "TEET 3090", class4 = "TEET 4290" };
            IDnumbers[1] = new IDnumber() { Name = "Sean Ward", ID = "900456318", year = "Junior", class1 = "ENGNR 4090", class2 = "ENGNR 3020", class3 = "ENGNR 3090", class4 = "ENGNR 4290" };
            IDnumbers[2] = new IDnumber() { Name = "Terrell Johnson", ID = "900456319", year = "Sophomore", class1 = "BUS 4090", class2 = "BUS 3020", class3 = "BUS 3090", class4 = "BUS 4290" };

```
    }
    public class IDnumber
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string class1 { get; set; }
        public string class2 { get; set; }
        public string class3 { get; set; }
        public string class4 { get; set; }


       public static void ProcessNumber(IDnumber myNum)
            {
                StringBuilder myData = new StringBuilder();
                myData.AppendLine(myNum.Name);   
                myData.AppendLine(": ");
                myData.AppendLine(myNum.ID);
                myData.AppendLine(myNum.year);
                myData.AppendLine(myNum.class1);
                myData.AppendLine(myNum.class2);
                myData.AppendLine(myNum.class3);
                myData.AppendLine(myNum.class4);  
                MessageBox.Show(myData.ToString());
            }

        public string GetDataFromNumber(string ID)
        {
            IDnumber[] IDnumbers = new IDnumber[3];
            foreach (IDnumber IDCandidateMatch in IDnumbers)  

            { 

                if (IDCandidateMatch.ID == ID)
                {
                 StringBuilder myData = new StringBuilder();
                 myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.Name);   
                 myData.AppendLine(": ");
                 myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.ID);
                 myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.year);
                 myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.class1);
                 myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.class2);
                 myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.class3);
                 myData.AppendLine(IDCandidateMatch.class4);  
                 //return myData;
                 return myData.ToString();
    }
}
return "";
```

}
        }

```
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry you need to rephrase your question its not at all clear.

Comment: im sorry, i get an error saying GetDataFromNumber is not defined and not accepting a first argument of type....however GetDataFromNumber is used/defined in second set of code in another .cs file...what could i do to correct this!?!

Comment: Do you actually have a class called GetSchedule?  If so, it might be helpful to include this definition in the question.

Comment: Yes i do have a class called GetSchedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the GetSchedule class is in the same namespace that you are trying to call it from, or that it is referenced.

It looks from your updated post like your function GetDataFromNumber is in a class called IDNumber - is this the problem?

Try:

```
IDnumber myNumber = new IDnumber();
myNumber.GetDataFromNumber(text);
```

Comment: all my .cs files are in the same project and under the same namespace Eagle_Eye_Class_Finder....

Comment: Okay - I've updated my answer.  It's difficult to tell from the code you've posted, but it looks like your function is not in the class that you're instantiating

Comment: yes you are right it is in the IDnumber class, but its public so shouldnt i be able to use it throughout my project?

Comment: Yes - but you have to instantiate the correct class.  If you instantiate the IDnumber class then you'll be able to call it using that.

Comment: OK that makes sense, i am a little new to C#, any help allowed on how i could instantiate this the correct way???

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure `GetDataFromNumber` is inside the `class` definition, and not after the closing brace?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are creating web forms and copying the code from one page to another. When you do this you have to be careful and make sure that you don't change the first directive in the page. It tells the web for what behind the code page it should look for where it should find the definitions and behind code logic. The reason you are having this problem is cause when you copied and pasted from one page to another it brought the directive for the other page which more than likely you do not have the functions you are calling within your page defined. So just make sure you changed the first line in your web page to point to the right `.cs` file and class from which it inherits.